# SCSS file not loading in live server and displaying two errors

Tags: html, css, sass, liveserver

I have an `SCSS` file and I compiled it into regular `CSS` using the `Live Sass Compiler` by Ritwick Dey.
When I run the file normally, I receive no warnings and everything works perfectly. But when I run my file in live server, they won't be applied and 1 warnings appear in the console (of the live server).

Error 1 :

```
   index.html:8   
   Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Users/emile/Desktop/Portfolio%20Website/styles/style.css
```

Here is the code :

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style: none;
}

:root {
  --color-primary: #191d2b;
  --color-secondary: #27AE60;
  --color-white: #FFFFFF;
  --color-black: #000;
  --color-grey0: #f8f8f8;
  --color-grey-1: #dbe1e8;
  --color-grey-2: #b2becd;
  --color-grey-3: #6c7983;
  --color-grey-4: #454e56;
  --color-grey-5: #2a2e35;
  --color-grey-6: #12181b;
  --br-sm-2: 14px;
}

body {
  background-color: var(--color-primary);
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  color: var(--color-white);
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

p {
  color: purple;
}/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Portfolio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="file://C:\Users\emile\Desktop\Portfolio Website\styles\style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1ycn6IcaQQ40/MKBW2W4Rhis/DbILU74C1vSrLJxCq57o941Ym01SwNsOMqvEBFlcgUa6xLiPY/NS5R+E6ztJQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600;700;800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body class="main-content">
    <header class="section sec1 header active"></header>
    <main>
        <p>Fingers Crosset</p>
        <section class="section sec2 about"></section>
        <section class="section sec3 portfolio"></section>
        <section class="section sec4 blogs"></section>
        <section class="section sec5 contact"></section>
      </main>
</body>
</html>
```

PS: The SCSS is compiled and

Any ideas why this is happening  ?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check the directory for style.css stylesheet again? As far as I can see, you could just use './style/style.css' .Looks like the problem is invalid directory.